# Detailed balance of an energy function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, stochastic-processes

I'm having difficulties understanding a problem about the acceptance rules for a given energy landscape.

**The Problem**

Suppose a system in which the energy is a function of x only:
$$
e^{-\beta U(x)} = \theta(x)\theta(1-x) 
$$
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function. The question asks to write down the distribution of x in the canonical ensemble for two possible algorithms.

i.Generate a random change *x* between [-$\delta$,$\delta$]. Accept or reject the new x according to its energy.

ii. Generate a random number $\phi$ between [1,1+$\delta$]. With a probability of 0.5 invert the value of $\phi$ thus obtained. The new value of x is obtained by multiplying *x* with $\phi$.

a) Derive the correct acceptance/rejection rules for both schemes.

b) What happens when the acceptance rule of method (i) is used in the algorithm of method (ii)?

**My approach so far**

Starting with detailed balance
$$ 
N_i\cdot\alpha_{ij}\cdot acc_{ij} =N_j\cdot\alpha_{ji}\cdot acc_{ji}
$$ we can write

$$
\frac{acc_{ij}}{acc_{ji}} = \frac{N_j}{N_i}
$$
Supposing that $\alpha$, the probability of choosing the state in the first place, is symmetrical. Given that it is a canonical ensemble the probability per site equals

$$
P = e^{ \frac{F-E}{kT} }
$$
So i guess from this I have to calculate a distribution N depending on the scheme (*i* or *ii*). So the probability function can be calculated with

$$
\int_a^b p(E)dE
$$
I could substitute the energy, but than I wouldn't know what the integration limits would be. Also I have no idea if I'm on the right track, or I am thinking way too complicated. Anyone who could help?

Comment: As a comment, is this potential (finite square well between x=0 and x=1) really what you're trying to study? Are there walls at x=0 or x=1? It seems like there may be a steady flow out to infinity though, I mean, maybe it can stabilize...

Comment: its an infinite square well for U(x), right? with walls at x=0 and x=1.

Comment: Ah, I see, you take $\ln(0)$. I was thinking $\theta(x) + \theta(1 - x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So usually the acceptance criterion for an simulated annealing approach is "accept if $\operatorname{rand}(0,1) < \exp[(U_0 - U_1)/\tau]$," and this will always accept if $U_0 > U_1$ or occasionally accept otherwise. However if your energy goes infinite outside of this range then you get an $e^{-\infty} = 0$ result, and we instead accept with probability 1 any movement that is in the appropriate range $x\in(0,1)$. Those are apparently your acceptance rules.

Now you say that you're having trouble determining what the steady-state probability density $f(x)$ is. We know that $f(x)~dx$ is the probability of observing the particle between $x$ and $x+dx.$ Supposing indeed that we start with density $f(x),$ update with the above, and then obtain $f(x)$ again, we can work out the result. Call the random variable beforehand $Y$ and afterwards $X$.

We generate a $Z$ uniformly between $-\delta$ and $+\delta$, then calculate $X = Y + Z.$ When we want to add variables like this, we have a joint probability $j(y,z)$ that we start with (in this case the events are independent and $j(y,z) = f(y) \cdot u_\delta(z),$ of course) and we derive our new distribution $h(x)~dx$ by summing up all of the $j(y, z)~dy~dz$ which lead to an $X$ between $x$ and $x + dx.$ So $h(x)~dx$ must be equal to $j(y(x, z), z)~\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}~dx~dz,$ and in the summing case, this works out really cleanly to:$$h(x) = \int_{\Omega_z} dz~j(x-z, z).$$ Assuming the uniform distribution we find that $$h(x) = \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} dz~\frac{1}{2\delta}~f(x-z),$$ and we recover $f$ after we throw out all values which are outside $(0, 1)$:$$f(x) = \frac{h(x)~\theta(x)~\theta(1-x)}{\int_0^1 du~h(u)}.$$Solving this equation is what would be necessary to get an explicit probability distribution in closed form. You should in principle be able to get a differential equation for this thing which can possibly be solved for a suitable $f(x),$ and qualitatively it should be roughly-constant in the middle with fringes of size $\delta$ where it drops to 0.